# Assigning displacement/normal map to a single side of a cylinder

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a cylinder created like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 128 );
```

It is a flat cylinder, like a coin. When I ad a displacementMap & normalMap, I end up with textures on both side of the cylinder, but I only want the maps to be on one side.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a [`THREE.CylinderGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CylinderGeometry)  a separated material for the shaft, the top plane and the bottom plane can be set:

```
var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#ff0000'});
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#00ff00'});
var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#0000ff'});
var materialList = [material1, material2, material3];

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 128 );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialList);
```

See the code snippet:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, mesh;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, -100, -100);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
  
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
  
    var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#ff0000'});
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#00ff00'});
    var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'#0000ff'});
    var materialList = [material1, material2, material3];

    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 128 );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialList);

    scene.add(mesh);
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script-->
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `thetaLength` option of [CylinderGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CylinderGeometry) to separate it into two pieces.

```
// Create two half-cylinders.
var part1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 128, 1, false, 0, Math.PI );
var part2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 2, 128, 1, false, Math.PI, Math.PI );

// Add the half-cylinders to a group, with different materials on each.
var group = new THREE.Group();
group.add( new THREE.Mesh( part1, material1 ) );
group.add( new THREE.Mesh( part2, material2 );
```

If you need more custom control than this, you probably want to use a modeling program like Blender to set up UVs and texture the cylinder.